# Раскидать запрос помесячно

Tags: sql-server

Привет.

Написал запрос:

```
select Site_name, COUNT (Status_site) as Num_contract from
(select Site.SiteID as Site_ID, Contract.Status as Status_site, Site.Code as Site_name from Site 
inner join Contract on Site.SiteID = Contrack.SiteID 
and Created between Getdate() - 365 and Getdate()
and Contract.Status = 3) t group by Site_name;
```

То есть я имею две колонки  - Название компании и во второй, сколько за последний год мы имеем закрытых контрактов. Все работает, но задача.

Автоматически раскидать помесячно, чтобы текущий месяц и назад на 12 месяцев (Getdate() - 365), но было 12 колонок (с марта 2015 по март 2014).

Есть ли вариант автоматом это сделать???

Answer (score 1):

```
 ... GROUP BY YEAR(Created), MONTH(Created), Site_name;
```

Comment: Все хорошо, но ругается на Created..

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'Created'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'Created'.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения желаемого вами результата необходимо использовать [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT count(Contract.STATUS) AS Num_contract
        ,Site.Code AS Site_name
        ,datename(month, Contract.created) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(Contract.created)) AS period
    FROM Site
    INNER JOIN Contract ON Site.SiteID = Contract.SiteID
        AND Contract.Created BETWEEN Getdate() - 365
            AND Getdate()
        AND Contract.STATUS = 3
    GROUP BY Site.SiteID
        ,Site.Code
        ,datename(month, Contract.created) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(Contract.created))
    ) AS t
PIVOT(sum(num_contract) FOR period IN ([March 2014],[April 2014],[May 2014],[June 2014],[July 2014],[August 2014],[September 2014],[October 2014],[November 2014],[December 2014],[January 2015],[February 2015],[March 2015])) AS pvt
```

Более сложный вариант, для динамического списка столбцов:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Columns = ISNULL(@Columns + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(period)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT datename(month, Contract.Created) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(Contract.Created)) AS period
    FROM Site
    INNER JOIN Contract ON Site.SiteID = Contract.SiteID
        AND Contract.Created BETWEEN Getdate() - 365
            AND Getdate()
        AND Contract.STATUS = 3
    ) AS periods

SET @Query = N'SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT count(Contract.STATUS) AS Num_contract
        ,Site.Code AS Site_name
        ,datename(month, Contract.created) + '' '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(Contract.created)) AS period
    FROM Site
    INNER JOIN Contract ON Site.SiteID = Contract.SiteID
        AND Contract.Created BETWEEN Getdate() - 365
            AND Getdate()
        AND Contract.STATUS = 3
    GROUP BY Site.SiteID
        ,Site.Code
        ,datename(month, Contract.created) + '' '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(Contract.created))
    ) AS t
PIVOT(sum(num_contract) FOR period IN (' + @Columns + ')) AS pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```